# How to resolve the never ending web api request

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am a beginner in ASP.NET Web Api. So i started with this small project from pluralsight. I had the project downloaded and the only problem is that whenever i started the web api and as soon as i entered some URL any (get or posts) the request goes in a never ending loop. I tried using the fiddler and saw something like this in the log.

> 05:04:40:9644 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes
> long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255
> bytes.
> https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
>
> 05:04:40:9944 HTTPSLint> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes
> long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255
> bytes.

The same message for all my api calls again and again from the browser.
Can anyone help me on this.. any help would be much appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: Did you do any debugging?  Do you see your controller methods running?

Comment: No I did not see any controller method running. I placed a breakpoint in startup.cs and global.asax it does not hit.

Comment: What server is your code running in that it supports SSL?

Comment: Its running in IIS express

Comment: Did you configure SSL in IIS Express, because if not then those error messages are not even relevant to the question.

Comment: So the controller methods are hitting now and the exception I am getting is the common error while getting the data from repository..
A network related instance error occurred........
my db file is in the local app_data folder of the project and the web config looks somewhat like this..sql server is not installed in this machine so I am using the db files directly

Comment: I suggest you delete this question and create a new one with all the relevant information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExpenseTrackerContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ExpenseTrackerDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>